# How to include an opt-out link (with token) in a reminder?

Tags: tokens, scheduled-reminders

I'm new to working with Scheduled Reminders, and am trying to figure out how to include our org's standard forward, opt out and sent-from info in each reminder, as we do with bulk Civi emails.

Our email template includes this:

====

## To forward this to a friend {action.forward} To never receive any email from the RFC {action.optOutUrl} This email is sent from: {domain.address}

But those tokens don't seem to work when I copy and paste into reminders. I don't understand why, or how to properly set up forward, opt out and sent from address in reminders.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done - because that token was created with CiviMail in mind.  There was a sense that scheduled reminders wouldn't be used for something that required an opt-out - but of course, people always want to use the software in new and interesting ways!

Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to get this one unless someone writes an extension to do so, or submits a patch to core CiviCRM.

Comment: Personally, regarding the opt-out link, I think this is a case of "Yes, it should work, but no it doesn't" . I wouldn't consider using scheduled reminders for membership renewals as "new and interesting", and I thnk we should have been able to foresee that someone receiving a membership reminder might want to opt out of future emails if they have decided not to renew. But I do agree that we can't expect the core team to "fix" this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to give them an option to set selves to 'do not mail' then, while not an ideal solution, for users of Drupal a webform can be used to allow people to set themselves to opt-out, set to 'do not send', etc

Your scheduled reminder would therefore need to include a checksum to the webform, the construction of which is explained on the civi tab of the webform

Answer (score 1):

We get around the lack of an opt-out link in what could be a very labour-intensive way.

We link the words "opt-out" to an email (rather than a URL) and pre-fill it with  an email address (info@...), subject (Please don't send me any more emails) and text (eg. "Source: Membership reminder - three weeks out").

Fortunately our opt-out rate for membership reminders is only 2 or 3  per thousand and we can manage that manually.